# CSS and Placing Text Next To Image

Tags: css, image, text, alignment

I have some text and an image and I want to place the text on the right side of the image.
I have made the image float right but the issue is that I only want to 2 first line to be place next to the image.
I want the rest of the text stay under the image like when you turn float off.

URL Example:
http://salient.peterstavrou.com/5937-2/

I have the below code for the image:

```
.audiodownload {
  width: 120px !important;
  float: left;
}
```

I am using WordPress and HTML in page is:

```
 <h2>Good Audiobook</span></h2>

  Click on the image below to see if the Audiobook is available.
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=The+7+Habits+of+Highly+Effective+People+audiobook" target="_blank"><img class="audiodownload" src="http://www.peterstavrou.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/YouTube-MP3-Audio.jpg" alt="Audiobook Download" /></a>
 If the Audiobook is available then you can download it to your computer as an .mp3 audio file by following these instructions
&nbsp;

The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People is recognized as one of the most influential audiobooks ever recorded. In this Audiobook Stephen R. Covey presents a holistic, integrated, principle-centered approach for solving personal and professional problems. 
With penetrating insights and pointed anecdotes, Stephen Covey reveals a step-by-step pathway for living with fairness, integrity, honesty and human dignity - principles that give us the security to adapt to change, and the wisdom and power to take advantage of the opportunities that change creates.
```

Comment: Could you show us your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the style of the paragraph you want to be below the image use:

```
p {
    clear: both;
}
```

No floating elements allowed on the left or the right side of a specified p element. From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp